# How to deny Delete access in SVN

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn

I have Version Control Software (SVN) installed in my server. I can able to grant/deny read, read-write, no-access to all the users.

Is it possible to deny Delete access to particular folder in SVN so that users are able to Checkout / Commit / Add files to SVN and not to delete the files in the SVN Repository.

Comment: Why you afraid the delete operation? SVN store all revisions, and deleted file could be restored at any time

Comment: Yes, we can retrieve the files. But this was the user requirement to deny delete access to specific folder. So i surfed everywhere but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

No, directly. Write access assume "add|change|delete"

But you can write and use pre-commit hook, which will block unwanted delete